# MfMailComposeViewController Device Crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

My app crashes when clicking to compose mail on a device when there is no mail account added. Anyone have an idea what I might be doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks in advance.

```
- (IBAction)sendMail:(id)sender {
    MFMailComposeViewController *mail  = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    NSArray *recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@""];
    mail.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [mail setSubject:@""];
    [mail setToRecipients:recipients];
    [self presentViewController:mail animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should include a complete error message whenever you ask question about an error you are getting.

But from your description you should be doing the following:

```
- (IBAction)sendMail:(id)sender {
    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
        MFMailComposeViewController *mail  = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        mail.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        [self presentViewController:mail animated:YES completion:NULL];
    } else {
        // let user know they can't send email
    }
}
```

Also note that there is no reason to set the subject or recipients if you don't have any values to set.

Comment: If it's no trouble what would I have to add to let the user know they can't send an email.

Comment: A common way would be to use a `UIAlertView`.

Comment: k is there a way to make an UIalertview only appear once?

Comment: You would need to keep track of that yourself. A simple `BOOL` stored in `NSUserDefaults` would be a typical approach.